# Why is my installed Progressive Web App dropping my session cookie

Tags: web, cookies, progressive-web-apps, session-cookies, mobile-website

I have a website that's several years old that I run on both desktop and mobile. On mobile I "install" it with both firefox and chrome and add a home screen icon for each.

My HTTPS only site has a rolling session in an HTTP cookie that expires if you don't use it, and this has worked for years but in the last few months, both the installed mobile versions on Android have started to require me to log in every day. Navigating around the app works fine as does backgrounding and returning to it a few hours later, but if I swipe the app away or leave it for longer (overnight, for example), and then reopen it, I need to enter my credentials.

I've cleared all data and reinstalled, and even tried on a different device. If the apps are not installed, it still works on both mobile and desktop.

I know the technologies as well as the terminology around mobile web apps is ever evolving but I cannot find any recent changes with the browsers or android that might explain this. One thought I had is that I am not yet using service workers, but I can't see a reason why that would mean it would no longer persist a cookie.

Any thoughts, oh wise collective? Thanks.